# Save QString in QSettings without quotes

Tags: qt, qstring, qt6, qsettings

I save some values in my `.ini`-file which works fine.

Now I want to save a QString in the file, which I put together inside my application.

```
QString s = "xwr289vjkloji9";

QSettings settings("file.ini", QSettings::Format::IniFormat);
settings.setValue("dbp", s);
```

Inside my `file.ini` it saves `dbp="xwr289vjkloji9"`

Basically this is right, but I need the String **without quotation marks**. Is there any way to remove them or should I save the String differently?

I cannot cut the first and last letter, because the quotes do not exists inside the String, they're just the String-identifier.

My only option now is to cut the quotation marks when receiving the value back from the file but I want to try it without, maybe there is a way.

Comment: Maybe this is possible, but why? Do you need QSettings? If you want just to write a file you can use the `QFile file` with its open write and close function. I wrote a QByteArray and the quotations marks are not stored to the file.

Comment: I use QSettings for some sort of configuration-file-management. I don't want simple IO via QFile. Nevertheless the quotes inside the .ini file cannot be removed. But I should be okay with it because when I retreive the settings, Qt is not using the quotation marks as an own symbol, so this is alright. It just stores the quotes inside the .ini-file for QString-identification.